# "Devise.secret_key was not set." deploying to Openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, openshift

First, I'm aware this question has been asked and answered several times before - I have tried the solutions given, and had no luck.

I'm running Ruby 2.0.0 Rails 4.2.6, Devise ~> 3.5, and deploying to Redhat Openshift. Whenever I try to deploy (or similarly invoke Rails, such as with `bundle exec rails c` while ssh'd in) I get the following error:

```
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

   config.secret_key = '2d229ab5ed60d38692a890544be96c8108040e18e4653832e2688dc1bed378afe6ef0f3386692f3c9b65336aba5b8e8e500accc2eadc6e70d6bc6c92f41c97fb'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
```

As I understand it, Devise under Rails 4+ will use `Rails.secret_key_base` as its secret key, which I'm pretty sure I have set. I have just the following occurrence of `secret_key` in my repo:

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Secret key base
  config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
end
```

I have verified that the environment key is set on Openshift, in the Rails context:

```
[ repo]\> bundle exec env | grep SECRET_KEY
SECRET_KEY_BASE=c509...
```

I have also tried being more explicit with setting the key into Devise:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
  # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
  # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
  # Devise will use the `secret_key_base` on Rails 4+ applications as its `secret_key`
  # by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
  config.secret_key = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] if Rails.env == 'production'
end
```

..but I still get the same error.

What have I missed?

Comment: Can you try to deploy your project on Heroku? Heroku does this automatically for me on rails 5. Just see if the problem persists.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal - I haven't tried; but I'm not sure I would expect it to just work on heroku. I've found the support files needed to be significantly different between the two platforms.

Comment: Well the thing with Heroku like I mentioned before is it indeed did set everything automatically. Glad you found your answer though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel silly. I hadn't set `RAILS_ENV`, so it was running as development. A simple:

```
rhc set-env RAILS_ENV=production
```

sorted everything out.

Comment: Yes, this error comes up if RAILS_ENV is not set correctly.  I had it incorrectly set to 'PRODUCTION', which is not the same as 'production'.